# Inner 'for-loop' is not continuing to the outer 'for-loop' after it's finished

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iteration, continue

In JavaScript, I'm running a for-loop (LOOP A) and another for-loop inside it (LOOP B). It's all working perfectly apart from the fact that once 'LOOP B' has finished running (up to all its 7 iterations), 'LOOP A' will not continue to run its 2 remaining iterations, no matter what I do to it - even whether or not I use the 'continue;' statement at the bottom.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

```
// Global variable
var current_ID = null;

function example_function()
{
    // LOOP 'A'
    for(var a = 1; a <= 3; a++)
    {
        // LOOP 'B'
        for(var b = 1; b <= 7; b++)
        {
            // SET 'current_ID' VARIABLE FOR EACH LOOP ITERATION
            current_ID = document.getElementById('text_box').getElementsByTagName('div')[b].getAttribute('id');

            // CHECK 'current_ID' VARIABLE FOR A SPECIFIC STRING
            if(current_ID == "example")
            {
                // do something
            }

            else
            {
                // do something else
            }
        }

        // CONTINUE 'LOOP A' AFTER EACH INSTANCE OF 'LOOP B' HAS FINISHED RUNNING
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: continue makes no sense, if placed at the end of the loop for continuing, which happens by design without any code as well..

Comment: @NinaScholz Oh ok, but even without it, the outer 'for-loop' does not continue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: continue at the end of the loop is redundant, your code loops correctly - check the **developer** tools console for errors - especially in code you have not provided

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do anything with `a`, so how would you know it's not running?  There's nothing in the code above that would make the outer loop not work.

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/76xohLg6/ Give us a [mcve]

Comment: @JaromandaX Understood. I tried it many times without the 'continue;' at the end, and with various other methods but it still did not continue to run the outer 'for-loop'.

Comment: Put the line `console.log('Outer loop, iteration nr. ', a);` as a first line of your loop A, and the line `console.log('Inner loop, iteration nr. ', b);` as a first line of your loop B. Open the developer tools (usually with F12) and check the output.

Comment: Please make sure that you don't have any `return` statements inside B and A loops.